# QuickSort - List Interface Java

Tags: java, quick-sort

Yes, this is one of my assignments.

**Question:**

I am asked to rewrite a generic QuickSort algorithm using only Java List Interface.
The purpose is that the algorithm can be executed for both LinkedList and ArrayList with any type extends Comparable interface. Professor suggests me that I should think stackwise and list approach (instead of in-place approach), using as less memory as possible and still maintain O(nlogn) complexity.

**What I got so far**

I have these lists `lessThanPivot, equalPivot, greaterThanPivot` to store the partitions, `sortedList` to store the output sorted array.
These lists are put on top of my class to reuse instead of instantiate them in every pass.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class QuickSort<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    public List<T> lessThanPivot, equalPivot, greaterThanPivot, sortedList;

    /**
     * A generic recursive QuickSort algorithms which should work on any Comparable Objects.
     * @param data: the list of items to be sorted
     * @return
     */
    public void quickSort(List<T> data, int start, int end)
    {
        if (start > end) return;
        end = Math.min(data.size(), end);
        T pivot = null;
        //Construct buffer lists
        ListIterator<T> iterator = data.listIterator(end);
        while (iterator.hasPrevious() && iterator.previousIndex() >= start)
        {
            T current = iterator.previous();
            if (pivot == null) pivot = current;
            if (current.compareTo(pivot) < 0) lessThanPivot.add(current);
            else if (current.compareTo(pivot) == 0) equalPivot.add(current);
            else greaterThanPivot.add(current);
            iterator.remove();
        }
        int lessThanPivotStartIndex = start + greaterThanPivot.size() + equalPivot.size();
        int greaterThanPivotEndIndex = start + greaterThanPivot.size() - 1;
        copyBufferListsToOriginalList(data);
        //Recursively sort the less than pivot
        if (lessThanPivotStartIndex < end && end <= data.size()) quickSort(data, lessThanPivotStartIndex, end);
        //In case all the lessThanPivot and equalPivot has been moved to output array, recursively call to sort the whole data
        //as it now contains only greaterThanPivot
        else if (lessThanPivotStartIndex > data.size()) {quickSort(data, 0, data.size()); return;}

        //Recursively sort the greater than pivot
        if (greaterThanPivotEndIndex > start) quickSort(data, start, greaterThanPivotEndIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Function to copy back the buffer lists to original list
     * @param data
     */
    private void copyBufferListsToOriginalList(List<T> data)
    {
        if (lessThanPivot.isEmpty() || lessThanPivot.size() <= 1) {
            copy(lessThanPivot, sortedList);
            copy(equalPivot, sortedList);
            if (greaterThanPivot.size() <= 1) copy(greaterThanPivot, sortedList);
            else copy(greaterThanPivot, data);
        }else {
            copy(greaterThanPivot, data);
            copy(equalPivot, data);
            copy(lessThanPivot, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to copy items from one list to another using iterator
     * @param source: The source list
     * @param destination: The destination list
     */
    private void copy(List<T> source, List<T> destination)
    {
//        destination.addAll(source);
//        source.clear();
        ListIterator<T> iterator = source.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            destination.add(iterator.next());
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

This is how I am instantiating these lists and calling QuickSort class

```java
public class MainArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maximumNumberOfItem = (int) Math.pow(10, 1);
        List<Integer> toBeSorted;
        QuickSort<Integer> qs = new QuickSort<>();
        qs.lessThanPivot = new ArrayList<>();
        qs.equalPivot = new ArrayList<>();
        qs.greaterThanPivot = new ArrayList<>();
        qs.sortedList = new ArrayList<>();    
    }
}
```

Ideally, I should have `MainLinkedList` class, which is identical with `MainArrayList` but these lists will be `LinkedList` instead.

**Problems**

- Even though my QuickSort can sort correctly, but it runs quite slow compare to recursive in-place versions.
- I got StackOverflow exception when n = 10,000.

I am not sure what is wrong and what could I improve on my program.

Thanks for your all advice and stay safe.

Comment: `O(nlogn)` *time* sticking to *list instead of in-place* may prove challenging with `java.util.ArrayList<>`: please show/compare run time for a linked variant.

Comment: @greybeard I've just updated the question with my classes.

Comment: @greybeard the purpose is the QuickSort can work with both ```LinkedList``` and ```ArrayList```. If the input array is ArrayList, then I will instantiate these lists as ```ArrayList``` and vice versa. (it's a homework assignment, you know)

Comment: I have a strong feeling that my recursive calls are causing the slowness ...

Comment: Show at least one setup where your code did seem to sort: I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` immediately trying to sort *{ 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0 }*. Better yet, show your *unit tests*.